# How to transform a numeric variable containing a date (YYYYMMDD) into a POSIXct format variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which one of the columns is `date`, but it is as a number. I want to transform it to POSIXct format, but I don't know how.

I thought of using different functions (`gsub`, `substr`, etc), but none of them allows me to add "-" between numbers at specific positions as far as I know.

How could I do it?

As an example, I have this data frame `df1`:

```
df1<- data.frame(date=c(20160801,20160802,20160803),
                   var1=c(4,56,76))

> df1
      date var1
1 20160801    4
2 20160802   56
3 20160803   76
```

I want to get this:

```
> df1
        date var1
1 2016-08-01    4
2 2016-08-02   56
3 2016-08-03   76
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Don't bother adding `-` or loading an extra package, just specify a format without spaces - `as.Date(as.character(df1$date), format="%Y%m%d")`

Comment: If you _really_ want class `POSIXct`: `as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(df1$date), "%Y%m%d"))`. But I suspect an object of class Date will do just as well.

Comment: @neilfws - why the extra `strptime`? - just go direct - `as.POSIXct(as.character(df1$date), format="%Y%m%d")`

Comment: @thelatemail yeah that too :) I initially omitted "format = " when I tried that, which generates an error.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks for your comments!! I think my post is a duplicate... I didn't find the posts you mentioned... Do I remove my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that pretty easily with `lubridate`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1<- data.frame(
  date=c(20160801, 20160802, 20160803),
  var1=c(4, 56, 76)
)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R,

```r
df1 <- data.frame(date=c(20160801,20160802,20160803),
                  var1=c(4,56,76))

> df1
      date var1
1 20160801    4
2 20160802   56
3 20160803   76
```

Use the function `as.Date.character` with the `tryFormats` argument defined as being defined in the same way as your data is currently. In this case, `"%Y%m%d"`.

```r
df1$date <- as.Date.character(df1$date, tryFormats = "%Y%m%d")

> df1
        date var1
1 2016-08-01    4
2 2016-08-02   56
3 2016-08-03   76
```